# How to write back to a certain cell in google doc spreadsheet using python

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

So the problem is, i get some information from first column of the row (for example A2 ) from the spreadsheet, then i will do some checking with that information, after that i want to write back to the next column in the row the result, how do i do that? Is there a certain function to allow me to indicate the column behind, in front, above, below? So i can write information in that cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, the docs for Google Spreadsheet API in Python are [here](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/1.0/developers_guide_python.html).  To create or update a cell, see [here](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/1.0/developers_guide_python.html#updateCell); to get the "cell range feed" you need, see [here](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/1.0/developers_guide_python.html#cellsFeedExample) -- basically to say "below" for example, get the cell feed for the specific column you want and the two rows (the one you're reading and the one you're writing), read one of the cells (the top one in the range), update the other one (the bottom one in the range).

For details of the protocol underlying the Python API, see [here](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/1.0/reference.html#cells_Feed) (that's where you get info on what attributes &c exist for the various objects involved, for example).