# Batch updating specific google spreadsheet cells using python gdata

Tags: python, google-sheets, gdata, google-sheets-api, batch-updates

I found some information [here](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/wiki/UsingBatchOperations) about updating several cells at once using the python gdata library.

However, the example code refers to cells based on a single index, for instance updating only the first entry of the spreadsheet:

```
batchRequest = gdata.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetsCellsFeed()
cells.entry[0].cell.inputValue = 'x'
batchRequest.AddUpdate(cells.entry[0])
```

Suppose I want to update specific cells knowing their location, e.g. `R1C3` and `R2C2`. How would I go about doing this?  In other words, what do I replace `cells.entry[0]` with to access a specific row and column?

[This related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378104/how-to-write-back-to-a-certain-cell-in-google-doc-spreadsheet-using-python) would be promising, except all the links are dead.

Comment: I solved this for my use case by simply restricting the query range, and then using the known dimensions to convert (r,c) to the entry index.  Unsatisfying, because the width of the query had to be hardcoded.

Comment: I just answered a similar question at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23069694/insert-row-python-gdata-spreadsheets-client/27852459#27852459