# Samples or tutorial of reading/writing cells in google spreadsheets in Python using spreadsheet API

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to read/write cells in a google spreadsheet. The resources I've looked at are;

[gdata api](http://pythonhosted.org/gdata/docs/api.html) is mentioned in various places, but I can't see how this is used to talk to spreadsheets, there are no spreadsheet related methods AFAIKT.

[Spreadsheet API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?csw=1) reference seems to have the HTTP protocol, but involve parsing and constructing huge pieces of xml to basic things, and seems unwieldy, but I'm a noob python coder so maybe there is a more elegant way of using http & XML that I'm not aware of. If any one has any canonical code sample code for useing V3 of the API, that would be great.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378104/how-to-write-back-to-a-certain-cell-in-google-doc-spreadsheet-using-python), mentions samples on google, but all its links have rotted and now point to the v3.0 of the API and all the examples are gone.

BTW I need to use Oauth access tokens, I can't use client auth, so [gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread) is no good to me, unless someone can show me how it can use access tokens.

Answer (score 1):

python-google-spreadsheet https://github.com/yoavaviram/python-google-spreadsheet

It looks to use passwords rather than OAuth2.0 
For the OAuth2.0 I used this:
https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/python

Note: I am using the Java version, not Python.